# Making a dijkstra table

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to make a table with networkx which has two columns, one with the distance and one with the nodes which are removed from the selected node with that distance.

So under distance there should be, in this case, 3 rows with 0, 1 and 2. And under nodes there should be every node, for example 1 node removed from X should be in de row of distance 1.

I tried this and it gives the right distances and nodes but i don't know how to code it so it will show the way i want it to show.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
V = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "X"]
E = [("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ("C", "D"), ("X", "A"), ("X", "D")]
G.add_nodes_from(V)
G.add_edges_from(E)

distance = []
nodes = []
def shortestPath(node):
  print "Distance Nodes"
    for i in G.nodes():
       for j in G.nodes():
          if j not in nodes:
            nodes.append(j)
            print "%s\t%s" % ((nx.shortest_path_length(G, node, j), j))                  

shortestPath("X")
```

it shows it like this

```
Distance Nodes
1        A
2        X
1        C
0        B
2        D
```

Comment: Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to invert the dictionary produced by the shortest path output.
Here is one way to do it:

```
import networkx as nx                                                              
from collections import defaultdict                                                
E = [("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ("C", "D"), ("X", "A"), ("X", "D")]                   
G = nx.Graph(E)                                                                    
# compute single source shortest path length                                       
spl = nx.shortest_path_length(G, source='X')                                       

# invert dictionary with keys as distance and values as list of nodes              
length = defaultdict(list)                                                         
for n,l in spl.items():                                                            
    length[l].append(n)                                                            

# print inverted dictionary                                                        
for l in sorted(length):                                                           
    print l,length[l]
```